# Look in df list, return Boolean if all list elements have a substring

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a string column that contains a sequence of author names and their affiliations.

| Address |
| --- |
| 'Smith, Jane (University of X); Doe, Betty (Institute of Y)' |
| 'Walter, Bill (Z University); Albertson, John (Z University); Chen, Hilary (University of X)' |
| 'Note, Joe (University of X); Cal, Stephanie (University of X)' |

I want to create a new column with a Boolean TRUE/FALSE that tests if *all* authors are from University X. Note there can be any number of authors in the string.

Desired output:

| T/F |
| --- |
| FALSE |
| FALSE |
| TRUE |

I think I can split the `Address` column using

`df['Address_split'] = df['Address'].str.split(';', expand=False)`

which then creates the *list* of names in the cell.

| Address_split |
| --- |
| ['Smith, Jane (University of X)', 'Doe, Betty (University of Y)'] |

I even think I can use the `all()` function to test for a Boolean for one cell at a time.

`all([("University X" in i) for i in df['Address_split'][2]])` returns `TRUE`

But I am struggling to think through how I can do this on each cell's list individually. I think I need some combination of `map` and/or `apply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `split` but `expand` so you can `stack` into one big Series. Then you can use `extract` to get the name and location.

Then your check is that all the values are `'University of X'` which can be done with an equality comparison + `all` within a `groupby`. Since the grouping is based on the original index you can simply assign the result back to the original DataFrame

```
s = (df['Address'].str.split(';', expand=True).stack()
       .str.extract('(.*)\s\((.*)\)')
       .rename(columns={0: 'name', 1: 'location'}))
#                 name         location
#0 0       Smith, Jane  University of X
#  1        Doe, Betty   Institute of Y
#1 0      Walter, Bill     Z University
#  1   Albertson, John     Z University
#  2      Chen, Hilary  University of X
#2 0         Note, Joe  University of X
#  1    Cal, Stephanie  University of X

df['T/F'] = s['location'].eq('University of X').groupby(level=0).all()
```

---

```
print(df)                                                                                                                         
                                             Address    T/F
0  Smith, Jane (University of X); Doe, Betty (Ins...  False
1  Walter, Bill (Z University); Albertson, John (...  False
2  Note, Joe (University of X); Cal, Stephanie (U...   True
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the solution that best balances a straightforward approach I can understand with robustness. There is another wrinkle where a researcher can have multiple affiliations that this can also handle.
Professor, K (University B; Laboratory C); 

or none listed at all: 
Professor, G ();

Comment: I modified the `extract` to not look for the closing quote and added a `dropna()` to remove blank universities

```
s = (dim['Addresses'].str.split('\);', expand=True).stack()
       .str.extract('(.*)\s\((.*)')
       .rename(columns={0: 'name', 1: 'location'})
       .replace('', np.nan, regex=True)
       .dropna())
```

Also changed the new column definition to use `contains`

```
dim['T/F'] = s['location'].str.contains('University X').groupby(level=0).all()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.extractall` to extract all the universities in parentheses and check if matches with `University of X`.

```py
df['T/F'] = df['Address'].str.extractall(r"\(([^)]*)\)").eq('University of X').groupby(level=0).all()
```

```
                                             Address    T/F
0  'Smith, Jane (University of X); Doe, Betty (In...  False
1  'Walter, Bill (Z University); Albertson, John ...  False
2  'Note, Joe (University of X); Cal, Stephanie (...   True
```

Comment: I like this for compactness, but I have to admit I don't understand the detailed regex. Would be good to deploy but a challenge for me to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other options:

```
u = 'University of X'

df['Address'].str.count(u).eq(df['Address'].str.count(';')+1)
```

or

```
df['Address'].str.findall('([\w ]+)(?=\))').map(lambda x: set(x) == {u})
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
```

Comment: Thank you. The first option makes the most sense to me, a direct count. I've turned up edge cases now with multiple affiliations, or none, that would make this approach break.